# extract data from redhsift

Tags: sql, json, amazon-redshift

```
elements
[{"name":"email",
  "value":"abc@gmail.com",
   "nodeName":"INPUT",
   "type":"text"}, 

 {"name":"password",
  "value":"*****",
  "nodeName":"INPUT",
  "type":"password"}, 

  {"name":"checkbox",
   "value":null,
   "nodeName":"INPUT",
   "type":"checkbox"}]
```

I have data like this in redshift. How do I extract value abc@gmail.com from this. This query is for redshift. Please help me with the SQL. Elements is a column name and the value starts with [].

Query I tried:
select
   id,
   json_extract_path_text(ELEMENTS, 'name') as name1
from table

error:[XX000][500310] Amazon Invalid operation: JSON parsing error Details: ----------------------------------------------- error: JSON parsing error code: 8 ...

Comment: Why are you trying to extract JSON from a text field in a database? Wouldn't it be more sensible to process the JSON before you stored it in the database, so that you can use, I dunno, a structured query language, to pick the elements you want?  That said, have you looked at the native JSON parsing functions in Redshift? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT.html

Comment: this data is loaded by another vendor in our database directly. but now, i would need to extract from this. I tried json parsing and its failing with json parsing error.

Comment: Then show us the query you tried and the error you received!

Comment: select
   id,
   json_extract_path_text(ELEMENTS, 'name') as name1
from table .                       error:[XX000][500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: JSON parsing error Details: ----------------------------------------------- error: JSON parsing error code: 8 ...

Comment: Please edit your question, don't add code as a comment.  Please include the error message in the question.  Please confirm whether the text column contains strings starting with `elements [` or if it just starts with `[` and `elements` is just the column name.  Ideally, you should give enough information that someone could exactly reproduce your error; https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You can create UDF in python, for your case I've created one, please test and edit as suits:

```
create or replace function f_py_json (jsonVar varchar(512), 
jsonElemvarchar(10), occ integer)
  returns varchar(512)
stable
as $$
  import json
  asJson = json.loads(jsonVar)
  name_list = []
  ret=str(asJson['elements'][occ][jsonElem])
  return ret
$$ language plpythonu;

select f_py_json (id, 'value', 1) from test;

-- Input is {"elements":[{"name":"email","value":"abc@gmail.com"},{"name":"password","value":"*****"}]}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But i would need a sql. we are not using python.

Comment: @George sorry it couldn't solve your problem but again once the UDF is in you can use it in SQL.